# C++17 template класс со значением аргумента по умолчанию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, language-lawyer

Сразу прошу прощения, я не знаю что написать в заголовок, ниже я дал минимальный пример кода. Я использую компилятор MSVC C++17. Объясните, почему для некоторых сущностей нужно писать <> при инициализации шаблона, а для некоторых можно опустить (в случае, если для всех аргументов есть значение по умолчанию)? Например, я могу вызвать шаблонную функцию, или создать экземпляр шаблонного класса внутри функции без <>, но если я хочу объявить член класса, то я обязан использовать `A<> a` вместо `A a`.

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t i = 1>
class A {
public:
    size_t foo() {
        return i;
    }
};

template<size_t i = 1>
size_t foo() {
    return i;
}

class B {
public:
    A a; // error
    A<> a; // okey

    static size_t foo1() {
        return foo(); // okey
    }
    template<size_t i = 2>
    static size_t foo2() {
        return foo(); // okey
    }
};

int main() {
    A a; // okey
    auto &f1 = foo; // error
    auto &f1 = foo<>; // okey
    auto &f2 = B::foo1; // okey
    auto &f3 = B::foo2; // error
    auto &f3 = B::foo2<>; // okey

    return B().a.foo() + A().foo(); // okey
}
```

P.S. на godbolt другие компиляторы имели то же поведение, т.е., возможно, это какой-то стандарт, но я не знаю как загуглить.

Comment: Дополню, для возвращаемого типа функции тоже требуется `<>`, т.е. `A<> getA() {return A();}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможность не писать пустые `<>` для **класса** - это частный случай более крупной фичи - возможности выводить шаблонные параметры из аргументов конструктора (CTAD = class template argument deduction).

Поэтому разрешено это плюс-минус только там, где есть какой-то вызов конструктора (есть из чего выводить параметры).

Например так нельзя: `std::vector foo();`. А так можно: `std::vector v = {1,2,3};`.

Тогда почему в нестатическом члене класа нельзя? Потому что это бы странно работало. Инициализатор, который там подписан, можно переопределить в списке инициализации в конструкторе. К примеру, вот это заслуженно не компилируется:

```
struct A
{
    std::vector a = {1,2,3}; // Допустим T = int.

    A()
        : a{1.0, 2.0, 3.0} // Из-за этого {1,2,3} полностью игнорируется.
        // Что дальше? Оставляем T = int? Не менять же на double задним числом?
    {} 

};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Понадобилось несколько раз прочитать, чтобы понять понять ваш пример. К std::vector мы для примера приписали значение по умолчанию int. Не знал о CTAD. Наверное, всё же можно научить компилятор распознавать явные случаи для членов класса, как в случае с size_t, который не зависит от инициализатора, но стандартом ещё не описали. Для auto тоже раньше куда меньше мест куда можно поставить было, думаю, расширят и этот сахар.

Comment: @ATtiny13a-PU Про `size_t` мысль не понял. Он же не шаблон, там нечего выводить. Про то что в новых стандартах могут добавить - это вряд ли. Они же специально запретили, чтобы в ногу себе было сложнее выстрелить.